How do I get a moving rigid body to collide with a cloth?
I have a UV sphere with collisions and rigid body and a cloth with collisions, cloth and rigid body. I want the UV Sphere to collide with the cloth and cause ripples and normal cloth behaviour, but instead it stops dead and doesn't affect cloth physics at all. The UV sphere is animated towards the Cloth at an angle and then before impact becomes a rigid body again, just to get the velocity.
Here's a link to all the relevant images and gif (it won't let me send the gif...)- https://www.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/1e33lqg/how_do_i_get_the_moving_sphere_to_push_against/#lightbox
